# Error: Can't access 'this' in a field initializer to read vAnswer

Tags: flutter

why can't the `vAnswer` string variable be read?

This my script:

```
final String? vAnswer='tes';
Reflex reflex = Reflex(
  debug: true,
  packageNameList: ["com.whatsapp", "com.tyup"],
  packageNameExceptionList: ["com.facebook"],
  autoReply: AutoReply(
      packageNameList: ["com.whatsapp"],
      message:vAnswer,
  ),
);
```

please help what is the solution?

Comment: could you show which error is throwing by flutter??

Comment: Perhaps both your `vAnswer` and `reflex` are file scope variables?

Comment: vAnswer is not read

Comment: lib/main.dart:55:19: Error: Can't access 'this' in a field initializer to read 'vAnswer'.
          message:vAnswer,
                  ^^^^^^^

Comment: Reflex reflex = Reflex(
    debug: true,
    packageNameList: ["com.whatsapp", "com.tyup"],
    packageNameExceptionList: ["com.facebook"],
    autoReply: AutoReply(
      packageNameList: ["com.whatsapp"],
      message: "[Reflex] This is an automated reply.",
    ),
  );

Comment: i want change "[Reflex] This is an automated reply." to dynamic var

Comment: Please help solution